# Cassandra: recommission Decommission of a node

Tags: cassandra

> It is possible to "re-commission" a decommissioned node in Cassandra? If so, how? Which can be the safest procedure?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

To "recomission" (reinsert) a node, I'd verify with "nodetool ring" that the node had been decomissioned, remove the data directory (system and keyspace directories) on the decomissioned node and bootstrap the node again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Since I'm a beginner, how can I do the data dir removal?

Comment: Ok... found it! It is defined in the cassandra.yaml file. In my case it was at /var/lib/cassandra

Comment: What if a previously decommissioned node restarted, without having those directories wiped, and honoured the auto_bootstrap = true setting?

Comment: Decommissioned nodes will not attempt to bootstrap with incomplete data. This was done deliberately to handle the case where a decommissioned node was accidentally restarted. A node could serve incomplete data for a time if it accidentially joined. (I can't find the bug report, but I recall this was done sometime in 2.x) I believe this behavior can be over-ridden with a JVM option in /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh